# Field level Security Or Profile permission edit not working!

Tags: permissions, security

On a "section" of the Opportunity Object I am trying to give "read only" to a specific profiles or specific user however when I go to profile I am unable to edit profile permission of the object I am also unable to edit the permission at Field level. Where should edit these permissions for all users for specific fields in on the Opportunity Object ? I am system Admin

Comment: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/keep-data-secure-in-a-recruiting-app/create-custom-profiles

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to edit a Standard profile, you should first clone it, and then edit the clone.

Comment: 1.   After cloning & editing the standard profile do we replace the old standard profile with the new cloned profile? Will this not be risky as I will have to assign the  new users to the profile new profile.    2. Is there another method that can be used to change a specific section of an Opportunity Object to be read only - only specify fields to be read only

Comment: @Brain Oconnell   1. After cloning & editing the standard profile do we replace the old standard profile with the new cloned profile? Will this not be risky as I will have to assign the new users to the profile new profile. 2. Is there another method that can be used to change a specific section of an Opportunity Object to be read only - only specify fields to be read only